# How to set a page break in MPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to create a page break in mPDF, but not succeeding, regardless of following every possible manual instruction, with the current attempt using this info:

https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/pagebreak.html

**I am using mPDF version 8.0.2.**

My current attempt looks like this:

```
function pdf_generate_table_html($data)
{
    $page_length = 40;
    $pages = ceil(count($data) / $page_length);
    $keys = array_keys($data[0]);
    $html = '';
    $counter = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        $slice = array_slice($data, $counter, $page_length, true);
        $html .= '<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #dddddd;">';
        $html .= '<thead>';
        $html .= '<tr>';
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            $html .= '<th class="content" style="padding: 8px; background-color: #333333; color: #ffffff;">' . $key . '</th>';
        }
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $html .= '</thead>';
        $html .= '<tbody>';
        foreach($slice as $key => $entry) {
            $html .= '<tr>';
            foreach($entry as $value) {
                $html .= '<td class="content" style="padding: 8px;">' . $value . '</td>';
            }
            $html .= '</tr>';
        }
        $html .= '</tbody>';
        $html .= '</table>';
        $html .= '<pagebreak>';
        $counter += $page_length;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

The following happens:

1. Without the page break and the code that slices the data into separate tables,  the first page contains the header, second page contains ENTIRE table (and I want it split...).
2. With the page break, first page is blank, second page contains the header, third page contains 3 tables, correctly split, but resized and fit onto one page, fourth page is blank.

**Important:** Using `<div>` tags does not appear to be feasible for me, because I am using tabular data that may contain any number of columns, and I cannot find a way to force all columns to be the width of the widest item in a column.

Any idea what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: have you tried <formfeed> instead <breakpage>

Comment: @Eric, yes, I have - output is similar to `<pagebreak>` - table is not split, and blank pages in between.

Comment: maybe : don't loop over page. out <table> <thead> <tbody>, then use a single loop to output each row, don't output <pagebreak> inside, but set style of table with : page-break-inside: auto

Comment: Sorry - that did not work either. Thanks for trying though :-) I will keep hammering at it.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are counting the actual number of lines in the table as you are going through the data. The page break only occurs after the entire table has been built. You need to keep track of the number of lines of the table have been output (including the header portion) and break when the number of lines you want per page has been hit.

Comment: @Dave, I am slicing the array of data to be the size of 40. So the table gets sliced correctly, that I know, but the page break is not there. The way this works is now generating tables with 40 rows, each one with its heading, but it is not splitting the page. The logic around the array and where it should break is correct. I just can't get mPDF to do a page break.